# Looping over directories in $PATH variable

Tags: bash

I need to loop over all directories in $PATH variable. Something like this:

```
for directory in "$PATH"; do 
    echo $directory
done
```

So if my $PATH variable is `/usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/bin` I need to have a loop with five directories: `/usr/bin`,  `/bin`, `/usr/sbin`, `/sbin`,  `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/local/go/bin`

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best approach is this:

```sh
while IFS= read -r -d : ; do
  directory="$REPLY"

  printf '%s\n' "$directory"
done <<< "$PATH:"
```

which uses the `read` command to read "lines", with `:` being the line terminator. (Setting `IFS` to the empty string ensures that `read` won't try to split the line into words, in case your path contains any whitespace or whatnot.)

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative with bash is simply to create an array where each element holds a component of your `$PATH` and then you can simply loop over the array as needed, e.g.

```
dirs=( $(IFS=:; echo $PATH) )
for d in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    ## use d as needed
done
```

If you only need to traverse the list once, then ruakh's `while` loop is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable substitution to replace every colon in `$PATH` with newlines:

```
for p in ${PATH//:/$'\n'}; do
  echo $p
done
```

This won't work if there are spaces in the directories of `$PATH`